# Using plupload with aspx page form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, plupload

A little background. I am using plupload to upload files within my application.

The `url` passed is the url to my aspx where I handle all the processing of the file.

What happens is, the first time you browse for and select a file nothing happens. The second time, it posts back both form submissions immediately.

Can you find any glaring omissions from the below code?

```
// Initialize the uploader
uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
                    runtimes: 'html5,gears,flash,silverlight,browserplus',
                    browse_button: 'browse',
                    drop_element: 'uploadContainer',
                    container: 'uploadContainer',
                    max_file_size: '10mb',
                    multi_selection: false,
                    url: 'someURLHere',
                    filters: [{ title: "Pdf files", extensions: "pdf"}]
                });
```

FilesAdded event fires when (obviously) a file is added

```
// File Added event 
uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function (up, files) {
                    $.each(files, function (i, file) {
                        // Add element to file object
                        file.formattedSize = plupload.formatSize(file.size);

                    $('form').submit();

                    // Reposition Flash/Silverlight
                    up.refresh();
                });
```

Submit the form

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
                    uploader.start();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
```

HTML

```
<form id="uploadForm">
   <div id="uploadContainer">
     <span id="uploadDragText" style="display: none;">Drag and Drop items here</span
     <div id="fileList"></div>
     <button id="browse" class="ButtonSubmit">Browse...</button> 
   </div>
</form>
```

I was using this great answer as a starting point. [using Plupload with ASP.NET/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350686/using-plupload-with-asp-net-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix to this is actually very simple.

I needed to `init()` the uploader **BEFORE** I bound any events to it, as the `init()` actually binds some default handlers.

```
// Initialize the uploader
uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
                    runtimes: 'html5,gears,flash,silverlight,browserplus',
                    browse_button: 'browse',
                    drop_element: 'uploadContainer',
                    container: 'uploadContainer',
                    max_file_size: '10mb',
                    multi_selection: false,
                    url: 'someURLHere',
                    filters: [{ title: "Pdf files", extensions: "pdf"}]
                });


   uploader.init();

   // Then add in any of your event handlers.
```