# I want to upload videos / large files without flash plugin

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, video, file-upload

I want to upload video (basically large files) without using Flash Plugin. 
It would be better if it shows progressbar also.

Of course I don't want to use the browser's default browse button as it is not good for large files.

OR

Is there any javascript (or any js framework like jQuery) solution for uploading large files?
(prefferebly with progressbar)

Note : Currently I don't want to use HTML5

Comment: PS- If you dont want to use HTML5, or Flash.. Do you want to use Silverlight or gears?  If not.. then you need to write a propriety Form submitter that submits chunks of data programitically from the client using HTML4 POST.. What a beach!

Comment: You may can steal ideas from file-hosting sites, like rapidshare

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you bear explaining the idea in short.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A hidden gem in the internet is [PLUPLAOD](http://www.plupload.com/)

Before i found this I was bald from ripping my hair out in uplaoding files. plupload enables you to uplaod 2GB files or larger if you want, using chrome gears, html5, silverlight or flash proxies/capabilities

[image]

The best part is it detects what the current browser can handle and injects the correct proxy or handles the process manually in the core. If it does not support anything well then the user needs to upgrade his browser..

If you are using .NET here is a handler I found, tweaked and works well.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6109862/706363

There are plenty of PHP examples.

This is truly an awesome JavaScript plugin!

Comment: PLUPLAOD is a good thing. I'll keep it in mind for future use. +1. But This does not fits to my current need. I can not depend on any of the 3rd party plugin like flash/sliver light etc.

Comment: @Imdad You dont have to depend on them if you use this.

Comment: atleast one of them should be availabe. isn't it?

Comment: Yes atleast one should be avaialbe. Where are you using this? For old mobile phones? IE5.5? Atleast one will work. trust me! Unless you are working on 1990 standards

Comment: It should work with 1. MAC safari  2. Any other OS & browser.
The problem is the user may not have any of these plugins.

Comment: Ohhhh. Well this script INJECTS silverlight, flash as needed.or uses native support. You put the files on your server and the plugin INJECTS it into the client. Safari for MAC supports HTML5 ages ago, and Chrome for Safari supports Gears. The client does not need to install anything. You provide it all from your server. Plupload injects the proxy virtually runs it if it can and uses native support to handle chunking and progress support. You just have to make a handler on the server. Do you use jQuery at all?

Comment: Yes, I use jQuery a lot. I want to know what will happen in following case.
User is using MAC Safari. If user does not has any other plugin (I understand that PLUpload injects the uploader  plugin but, only when the browser have support for that). My site is not HTML5 site. Will it work? Will it inject the HTML5 code and will it work even my site is not HTML5?

Comment: Your site has nothing to do with that. Its the browser. IE5,6,7 DO NOT SUPPORT HTML5, even if your site is made for HTML5- it will gracefully degrade(and most liekly break in IE) WebKit(Chrome,Safari,FireFox) Support HTML5 loooong time ago. So if your site is asp.net2 codded in 2003 and you use plupload with the newest chrome.. PLUPLOAD will use html5 native support.not your site. Thats the beauty of this(think of it like a virtual machine on top of your site. ie you have server2003 but run server 2012 virtually inside 2003 and use the VM's IIS7.5 to run .NET4) Same concept. Just try it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these links,

- http://www.johnboy.com/blog/a-better-php-upload-progress-bar-using-jquery
- [jQuery ajax upload with progress bar - no flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714507/jquery-ajax-upload-with-progress-bar-no-flash)
- http://www.webappers.com/2011/01/24/jquery-file-upload-with-upload-progress-bar/

I did a normal google search and found these..

Comment: Yes, I have seen all of these. Their main focus is on progress bar which in my case has 2nd priority. Please first resolve my first priority i.e. Upload large file without flash file