# jquery multi file upload for asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, file-upload, multi-upload

i become stuck in a problem kindly help me in this matter.... problem is that i want a jquery multi file uploader to embed in asp.net page and requirement 
1)no use of flash plugin 
2)it support IE 
3)no use of html 5 
4) select multi files at a time like (gmail when we send email)

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For uploading multiple files using JQuery. I use JQuery Multifile plugin which is simple and easy to see. See this link [JQuery Multiple File Upload](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/)

Just inlcude this library and JQuery and its syntax is like

For html input

```
<input type="file" class="multi"/>
```

For Asp.net File upload control

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileup" runat="server" CssClass="multi" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you're not providing much information here therefore it's hard to answer your question. But I'll just give it a shot anyway.

You could try a solution like [Plupload](http://plupload.com/):

> Allows you to upload files using HTML5 Gears, Silverlight, Flash, BrowserPlus or normal forms, providing some unique features such as upload progress, image resizing and chunked uploads.

And there is already a question here about [using Plupload with ASP.NET/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350686/using-plupload-with-asp-net-c)

Plupload is very extensible and you can customize it to fit your own needs by enabling / disabling the uploading options it has to offer.